# InlineKeyboard не показывается в груповом чате

Tags: python, telebot, клавиатура

Я пробую разобраться в клавиатурах, прикреплённых к сообщению. И вот решил сделать команду, которая меняет язык. Создаю клавиатуру:

```py
keyboard_language = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard_language.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Українська (ua)', callback_data='ua' + str(message.chat.title) + str(message.chat.id) + ".txt"))
keyboard_language.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='English (en)', callback_data='en' + str(message.chat.title) + str(message.chat.id) + ".txt"))
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Choose language", reply_markup=keyboard_language)
```

Дальше идёт смена языка, что ни на что не должна влиять,
но вот, какие команды я использовал, что как-то связаны именно с клавиатурой:

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def query_handler(call):
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, text='Changed language')
    bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
```

А прикол в том, что в приватных сообщениях с ботом всё работает, а когда я пробую вызвать в чате с другими людьми, но сообщение с клавиатурой просто не отправляется, и я не понимаю почему. Думаю, тут проблема ещё с первым блоком кода, потому что когда я принтовал текст после каждой строки, то всё срабатывало, кроме `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Choose language", reply_markup=keyboard_language)`, но я вообще без понятия почему. Поможете решить проблему?

Comment: Рекомендую вместо вот таких конкатенаций `'ua' + str(message.chat.title) + str(message.chat.id) + ".txt"` использовать интерполяцию через f-строки. Вот так: `f"ua{message.chat.title}{message.chat.id}.txt"`

Comment: Спасибо, что подсказываете с такими мелочами, я ещё не очень опытен в таком

Comment: И, кстати, спасибо, что отредактировали мой вопрос с использованием ```python, я не знал, что так можно)